# Ternary jquery .click(function() {

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, ternary-operator

I am very new to jquery and I was given a task in which I want to display div#pgmenu2 on the click of a#local-popular.

I know I need my jquery to start like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#local-popular").click(function() {


    });
  });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<a id="local-popular" href="http://lh.com"><p>Popular Searches ▼</p></a>
   <div id="pgmenu2">
   <ul type="disc">
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#local-popular").click(function() {
      $("#pgmenu2").show();
    });
});
```

or you can use `.toggle` if you want to show/hide on subsequent clicks

```
$("#pgmenu2").toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

add display:none to the div:

```
<div id="pgmenu2" style="display:none">
   <ul type="disc">
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

and the js part is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#local-popular").click(function() {
        $("#pgmenu2").show();
    });
  });
```

or if u want to be able to hide it again u can use:

```
$("#pgmenu2").toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially set the `div #pgmenu2` to `display:none` in css

```
     #pgmenu2
          {
              display:none;
          }
```

and use the below code to show on click

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#local-popular").click(function() {
               $("#pgmenu2").show();
                 });
             });
```

//below code to show and hide onclick

```
             $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#local-popular").click(function() {
               $("#pgmenu2").toggle();
                 });
             });
```

//below code to show and hide onclick with a sliding motion

```
          $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#local-popular").click(function() {
               $("#pgmenu2").slideToggle();
                 });
             });
```

Comment: thank you! this was more than what i asked for, i appreciate it